# Java Spring exception: No property xxx found for type class xxx

Tags: java, spring, rest, annotations

I wanted to add a new repository method, to retrieve a list of elements.

Main Problem is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'insulinGTService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private xxx.xxx.xxx.repository.InsulinGTRepository xxx.xxx.xxx.service.jpa.InsulinGTServiceImpl.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'insulinGTRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No property storelistfromcontainer found for type class xxx.xxx.xxx.domain.InsulinGT
```

I kinda worked out, that it can't autowire the **repository** in **InsulinGTServiceImpl**, if you follow the error, you end up in the **InsulinGTRepository** with the error you can see beyond.

**InsulinGTServiceImpl**

```
    @Service("insulinGTService")
    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class InsulinGTServiceImpl implements InsulinGTService {

    @Autowired
    private InsulinGTRepository repository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<InsulinGT> findByID(Long insulinid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Lists.newArrayList(repository.findByUserid(insulinid));
    }

    @Override
    public InsulinGT save(InsulinGT insulin) {
        return repository.save(insulin);
    }



    @Override
    public List<InsulinGT> liststorelistfromcontainerSave(InsulinlistGT insulin) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return repository.storelistfromcontainer(insulin);
    }



}
```

**InsulinGTService**

```
public interface InsulinGTService {

    public List<InsulinGT> findByID(Long insulinid);
    public InsulinGT save(InsulinGT insulin);
    public List<InsulinGT> storelistfromcontainerSave(InsulinlistGT insulin);

}
```

In the **InsulinGTRepository** spring says, **Invalid derived query! No property storelistfromcontainer found for type InsulinGT!**

```
public interface InsulinGTRepository extends CrudRepository<InsulinGT, Long> {


    public List<InsulinGT> findByUserid (Long id);
    public List<InsulinGT> storelistfromcontainer(InsulinlistGT insulin);
}
```

**InsulinGT**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "insulin")
public class InsulinGT implements Serializable {                    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3333976984277807655L;
        private Long insulinid;
        private Long userid;
        private String ivalue;
        private String therapie;
        private String insulinname;
        private String einheit;
        private Date date;
        private Date time;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "insulin_id")
        public Long getInsulinid() {
            return insulinid;
        }

        public void setInsulinid(Long insulinid) {
            this.insulinid = insulinid;
        }

        @Column(name = "users_id")
        public Long getUserid() {
            return userid;
        }

        public void setUserid(Long userid) {
            this.userid = userid;
        }

        @NotNull    
        @Column(name = "ivalue")
        public String getIvalue() {
            return ivalue;
        }

        public void setIvalue(String ivalue) {
            this.ivalue = ivalue;
        }


        @Column(name = "date")
        public Date getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(Date date) {
            this.date = date;
        }


        @Column(name = "time")
        public Date getTime() {
            return time;
        }

        public void setTime(Date time) {
            this.time = time;
        }

        @Column (name = "therapie")
        public String getTherapie() {
            return therapie;
        }


        public void setTherapie(String therapie) {
            this.therapie = therapie;
        }

        @Column(name = "insulinname")
        public String getInsulinname() {
            return insulinname;
        }

        public void setInsulinname(String insulinname) {
            this.insulinname = insulinname;
        }

        @Column(name = "einheit" )
        public String getEinheit() {
            return einheit;
        }

        public void setEinheit(String einheit) {
            this.einheit = einheit;
        }

}
```

I alredy tried out renaming the classes, but nothing helped. The old version without the new added method is working fine without any problem.
Every help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try reading the error message? Spring Data JPA is autogenerating a query based on the method names on the repository interface, and you don't have a matching property.

Comment: And how do I add the needed property. I guess it's in the InsulinGT, but how does the property look like, that's needed?

Comment: What are you expecting the `storelistfromcontainer` method on the repository interface to do?

Comment: You need to understand how Spring Data JPA generates the implementation for the method name. The name you have specified does not correspond with anything Spring Data JPA knows how to handle

Comment: @chrylis the method should work like the save method implemented in the CrudRepository, to push an element in the database (in this case the whole list of elements should be pushed into the database)

Comment: So just use the `save(Iterable<InsulinGT>)` that already exists.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, after I wrote the last comment, I took a closer look at the API Documentation and saw this one too and thought crap, why didn't I watch this one closer before.
Gonna give it a try

Comment: @chrylis Thanks for your help with the     save(Iterable<InsulinGT>) it is working perfectly now.
If you could post this solution as answer, I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.create-instances

You need to define the custom method in a separate interface.

```
public interface CustomRepo {
    public List<InsulinGT> storelistfromcontainer(InsulinlistGT insulin);
}
```

And now define a base interface as this

```
public interface InsulinGTRepository extends CrudRepository<InsulinGT, Long>, CustomRepo {
    public List<InsulinGT> findByUserid (Long id);
}
```

Also for provide a bean that satisfies CustomRepo:

```
public class CustomRepoImpl implements CustomRepo {
    @Override
    public List<InsulinGT> storelistfromcontainer(InsulinlistGT insulin) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperation("TODO");
    }
}
```

Note the name CustomRepoImpl is IMPORTANT (the default bean look up strategy for the `extension` interface is by suffixing with `Impl`.